# Customer Session Delay

Tags: magento2, session, customer-session

I have a .phtml file that loops through dropdowns. There are 6 dropdowns belonging to two different groups (so 3 dropdowns per group).

I set a session on button click:

```
if ($this->getRequest()->getParam(self::USERBIKE)) {
    $block = $this->layoutFactory->create()->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Garage');
    if ($block->getGarageCollection()->getFirstItem()->getCustomerId()) {
        $block->getCoreSession()->setUserBike(1);
    }
}
```

Which I then use to check in the dropdown .phtml file:

```
if ($session->getUserBike() == 1) {
    $useUserBike = true;
    # etc.
}
```

However, nothing seems to happen.

I added some logging to check each dropdown to see what was going on:

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP. '/var/log/logfile.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);

# log each dropdown ID
$logger->info('OUTSIDE: '. $block->getDropdown()->getDropdownId());

# log Session value per dropdown
$logger->info('OUTSIDE USER BIKE SESH: '. $session->getUserBike());

if ($session->getUserBike() == 1) {
    $useUserBike = true;
    $userBike = $blockGarage->getGarageCollection()->getFirstItem();

    # log cur dropdown ID
    $logger->info('CURDROPDOWNID: '. $block->getDropdown()->getDropdownId());

    # log cur dropdown group ID
    $logger->info('CURFINDERID: '. $block->getDropdown()->getFinderId());

    if ($block->getDropdown()->getFinderId() == 1) {
        switch($block->getDropdown()->getDropdownId())
        {
            case 1: $compareTo = $userBike->getMakeId(); break;
            case 2: $compareTo = $userBike->getModelId(); break;
            case 3: $compareTo = $userBike->getYearId(); break;
            default: $compareTo = 0; break;
        }
    }

    # log compareTo value
    $logger->info(isset($compareTo) ? $compareTo : 'empty str');
    $logger->info('======================================'); # visibility break
}
```

The output of my logfile:

> 2019-01-09T16:33:47+00:00 INFO (6): OUTSIDE: 1
>   2019-01-09T16:33:47+00:00 INFO (6): OUTSIDE USER BIKE SESH:
>   2019-01-09T16:33:47+00:00 INFO (6): OUTSIDE: 2
>   2019-01-09T16:33:47+00:00 INFO (6): OUTSIDE USER BIKE SESH:
>   2019-01-09T16:33:47+00:00 INFO (6): OUTSIDE: 3
>   2019-01-09T16:33:47+00:00 INFO (6): OUTSIDE USER BIKE SESH:
>   2019-01-09T16:33:47+00:00 INFO (6): OUTSIDE: 4
>   2019-01-09T16:33:47+00:00 INFO (6): OUTSIDE USER BIKE SESH: 1
>   2019-01-09T16:33:47+00:00 INFO (6): CURDROPDOWNID: 4
>   2019-01-09T16:33:47+00:00 INFO (6): CURFINDERID: 2
>   2019-01-09T16:33:47+00:00 INFO (6): empty str
>   2019-01-09T16:33:47+00:00 INFO (6): ======================================
>   2019-01-09T16:33:47+00:00 INFO (6): OUTSIDE: 5
>   2019-01-09T16:33:47+00:00 INFO (6): OUTSIDE USER BIKE SESH: 1
>   2019-01-09T16:33:47+00:00 INFO (6): CURDROPDOWNID: 5
>   2019-01-09T16:33:47+00:00 INFO (6): CURFINDERID: 2
>   2019-01-09T16:33:47+00:00 INFO (6): empty str
>   2019-01-09T16:33:47+00:00 INFO (6): ======================================
>   2019-01-09T16:33:47+00:00 INFO (6): OUTSIDE: 6
>   2019-01-09T16:33:47+00:00 INFO (6): OUTSIDE USER BIKE SESH: 1
>   2019-01-09T16:33:47+00:00 INFO (6): CURDROPDOWNID: 6
>   2019-01-09T16:33:47+00:00 INFO (6): CURFINDERID: 2
>   2019-01-09T16:33:47+00:00 INFO (6): empty str
>   2019-01-09T16:33:47+00:00 INFO (6): ======================================

As you can see, The session doesn't have a value 'til the **4th** dropdown. Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

Minified Block Controller Session Code:

```
class Garage extends Tempalte
{
    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    )
    {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function getCustomerSession()
    {
        return $this->customerSession;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your block coreSession function code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your block code as below.

```
class Garage extends Tempalte
{
    protected $customerSessionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession
    )
    {
        $this->customerSessionFactory= $customerSessionFactory;
    }

    public function getCustomerSession()
    {
        return $this->customerSessionFactory->create();
    }
}
```